# I get a SyntaxError in Node.JS, but I can't figure out the origin of that error from the log messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am running a Node app on Azure. It's a Web API and when I try to call it, I see this message in the Node console:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:17:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

I ran my whole code through `eslint` and didn't find any syntax errors. It also runs fine on my local machine, but doesn't run on Azure.

The message above points to line 17 and column 23 in app.js, which is a `require`:

```
let warehouseExport = require('./routes/warehouse-export-api');
```

I ran `eslint` and `jshint` specifically on the file referenced above, and there are no syntax errors.

What are some other ways I can get the exact location of the syntax error, and why could it be that the code fails on Azure but runs on my local machine?

**What I tried:**

- Wrap in try-catch and grab the line number - it shows up `undefined`:

`try {
      var warehouseExport = require('./routes/warehouse-export-api');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error + ', line ' + error.lineNumber);
    }`

Comment: @RobertRowntree It didn't work before because I just added this new file. There are no additional build steps, the app is pretty simple, I used to just FTP the entire directory to the server and it was done.

Comment: @K48 have you tried to `console.log(error.stack)` inside `catch`? The trace you provided (as reported by Azure I guess) seems to miss leading lines that are usually shown in `SyntaxError` case.

Answer (score 3):

You should check version of nodejs you have installed on Azure. Maybe it's <= 4 and it doesn't support `let` keyword. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Turns out you were right! See my detailed answer below

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the error was that the Node version somehow got reset to 4.2.4.

When I go to Azure Portal and run `node --version`, I get version 8.1.4.

However, if I `console.log` the Node version inside my script, it is somehow still 4.2.4.

I will investigate why that happened and how to fix it, but for now it's clear that the bug is due to `async function` not being recognized by the old Node.

Update: the `package.json` file where the node version was specified got overwritten somehow, which is what caused the issue.